# Requesting With Parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, python-requests, clockify

I'm doing some experiments with the [Clockify API](https://clockify.me/developers-api). It uses curl but I figured a way with python requests.

In the Time-Entry Section there's a optional parameter you can pass. Basically without this parameter the duration format of the time-entry show's up in letters and numbers. It's the "consider-duration-format" parameter btw.

I tried passing this parameter through

```
url = 'https://api.clockify.me/api/v1/workspaces/{workspaceID}/user/{userID}/time-entry
headers = {'X-Api-Key': 'my_api_key',
           'content-type': 'application/json'}
data = {'consider-duration-format': True}
req = requests.get(url, data=data, headers=headers)
print(req.json())
```

The duration format didn't change so then I tried params

```
params= {'consider-duration-format': True}
req = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
print(req.json())
```

And unfortunately it also didn't work.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.../user/{userID}/...` (without the "s"), and `time-entries`?

Comment: sorry mb ^^;. Edited it.

Comment: Did you replace `workspaceID` and `userID` with real values in your url?

Comment: yep. And recently I tried ```req = requests.get(url, json=params, headers=headers)``` I sqaw it on another stackoverflow question and thought It would work